# Zero byte files after power-cycling 18.04 LTS

Tags: disk, ext4, data-corruption

I tried to reboot an 18.04 LTS machine but it didn't respond so after waiting some minutes I power-cycled the machine.

The machine started fine but I have found some of the recently edited files are now empty. This applies to at least 5 known cases including text files, a system file and files deep in a .git folder.

- Is this file-system fatally corrupted and unsafe to use?
- How would I know if this is a hardware issue?
- Is this a known risk just from power-cycling ubuntu?

Other info:

- Disk is a Samsung 970 Pro
- Ubuntu installed on an Ext4 partition (dual boot with windows)
- `Disks` cannot repair the boot disk (it's busy) need a live usb stick
- `smartctl` reports as follows:

## Updates

- running `sudo touch /forcefsck;sudo shutdown -r now` did not visibly check the disk
- Using a live disk, `Disks` check says that the partition is undamaged
- running `fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5` from a live disk returns no errors, exit code = 0

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB
Serial Number:                      S462NF0M616954M
Firmware Version:                   1B2QEXP7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            691,389,394,944 [691 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Sun Nov 17 01:01:26 2019 GMT
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0037):   Security Format Frmw_DL *Other*
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat *Other*
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     81 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     81 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.20W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        36 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    1,662,255 [851 GB]
Data Units Written:                 5,875,310 [3.00 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 20,271,726
Host Write Commands:                90,120,020
Controller Busy Time:               335
Power Cycles:                       95
Power On Hours:                     515
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   4
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      105
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               36 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               39 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Comment: I have no guess as to why your shutdown hung (look at `journalctl -b -1 -ex`), but it acts as if the disk buffers in memory didn't get flushed to physical disk. If you weren't forced to do a `fsck` on startup, the system thinks the disk is OK. You could force a `fsck` by `sudo touch /forcefsck;sudo shutdown -r now`. You can't use `Disks` on a mounted drive (a drive with at least 1 mounted partition) because, while `Disks` could update the data disk, is has no access to the kernel's in-memory copy of the disk metadata.  Thus, the need for the Live USB. Your data is lost.

Comment: thanks waltinator - I have run the fsck command but I didn't see any visible disk checking after the machine rebooted - what should I expect?

Comment: See above for updates. I have forced fsck from a live disk, no errors. I don't think I can trust this file system with known issues in system files. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is EXT4 filesystem's feature called "delayed allocation". Delayed Allocation was added in EXT4 for performance reason where data is NOT committed to disk immediately. This gives a great deal of performance boost at the cost of good amount of likelihood of complete data loss of uncommitted files during power failure.
Some the the delay can be in many seconds and power failure will cause uncommited files to be shown as 0 bytes in size. This is what I believe you are facing.

You need to carefully select filesystem mount options in /etc/fstab entries. For exmaple, `data=journal` option enables all data to be committed into the journal prior to being written into the main file system as well as disables delayed allocation feature.

You can read basic details about EXT4 flags [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) and all options [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt).
There is a nice discussion about these options in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127235/is-data-journal-safer-for-ext4-as-opposed-to-data-ordered) also.